# Add a column into the data frame when using lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

For the code below, I get a data frame (DF1) of one column and 120000 rows and the column is named as "value". However, I want to add another column for the iterator  i value used. For instance the column could be named "iterator value" and should have values like 5, 10, 15,20...60 in it.

```
DF1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(5,60,5), function(i) setNames(data.frame(rlnorm(n=10000, log(i^2 / sqrt((i*j)^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*j)^2 / i^2))))), "value")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
DF1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(5,60,5), function(i) 
       data.frame(iterator = i, value = rlnorm(n=10000, 
       log(i^2 / sqrt((i*j)^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*j)^2 / i^2)))))))
```

A bit shorter with `map_df` from `purrr` :

```
DF1 <- purrr::map_df(seq(5,60,5), function(i) 
           data.frame(iterator = i, value = rlnorm(n=10000, 
           log(i^2 / sqrt((i*j)^2 + i^2)), sqrt(log(1 + ((i*j)^2 / i^2))))))
```